# Scala - Injecting Generic type using guice when dependency class is also using same generic type

Tags: scala, generics, dependency-injection, guice

I want to inject dependency with Generic type using Guice. Find below example in scala which replicate the issue.

ProductModel.scala

```
trait BaseProduct  

case class Product() extends BaseProduct
```

CartService.scala

```
class CartService[A <: BaseProduct] @Inject()(productService : ProductService[A]) {
 def getCartItems = productService.getProduct
}
```

ProductService.scala

```
class ProductService[A]{
 def getProduct = println("ProductService")
}
```

Main.scala

```
object Main extends App {

  val injector = Guice.createInjector(new ShoppingModule)
  val cartService = injector.getInstance(classOf[CartService[Product]])
  cartService.getCartItems
}

class ShoppingModule extends AbstractModule with ScalaModule {
  override def configure(): Unit = {
    bind[BaseProduct].to(scalaguice.typeLiteral[Product])
  }
}
```

while running this Main.scala app getting below error.

```
service.ProductService<A> cannot be used as a key; It is not fully specified.
```

I have tried binding using codingwell library. But it doesn't help to identify ProductService Type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you create instance of cartService at that time **use typeLiteral to create instance** like

```
val cartService = injector.getInstance(Key.get(scalaguice.typeLiteral[CartService[Product]])
```

if you create instance like above you don't need to create module.
Create injector using default Module (i.e. useful if you have any other bindings in default Module.scala at application level)

```
val appBuilder = new GuiceApplicationBuilder()
val injector = Guice.createInjector(appBuilder.applicationModule())
```

and if you don't have any module you can skip passing module as argument and create injector without passing any module as well like

```
val injector = Guice.createInjector()
```